# How to build vaadin 14 project with Java Hipster?

Tags: java, vaadin, jhipster, vaadin-flow

Is there any way to build Vaadin 14 project with Java Hipster?

As Java Hipster is been making projects with angular react and vue can vaadin have a scope by hook or crook to be developed with Java Hipster?

Comment: You’d have to create a blueprint for Vaadin to integrate with JHipster. More at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8410

Comment: That seems to be hard ): .

Comment: Yes, it likely will be hard. If you really want to see Vaadin support in JHipster, you'll likely have to create it yourself or convince the Vaadin company to create a blueprint. I've talked to their CEO, Joonas Lehtinen, about it before but obviously they haven't invested in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can build a Jhipser/Vaadin application. You just create a Jhipster application and then manually add the Vaadin dependencies.  That would be the easiest way.
https://dev.to/cbeulke/rapid-development-with-jhipster-and-vaadin-as-simple-as-it-sounds-511